# code snippets and code complete support in cloud9

Tags: cloud9-ide

I have two questions:

1. Is there an option to save code snippets ?
2. IS there a support for code complete to php for example ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you done any research to find out if these tasks are possible before asking here?

Comment: Yes, the docs are short with no mention to snippets even in the features. code complete have no full support, for example in php it will complete global variables but nothing for session_ ....

Answer (score 1):

1. No option for that right now. You could do a feature request through support.
2. Yes, there is partial code completion support, see for example https://c9.io/site/blog/2014/07/announcing-the-all-new-cloud9-development-environment/. This should be extended with further support in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

1.If you now have support for saving Snippets, you should follow the
    [official documentation](https://cloud9-sdk.readme.io/docs/snippets) 

 2. Cloud9 -> Preferences -> Project Settings -> PHP Support -> Enable PHP code completation[Settings in UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpq89.png)